# Bootstrap - my content has a large white space

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

As you can see here:
[image]
My content has a large white space. My content HTML is below. Not sure why it isn't aligning properly and has a large whitespace. Makes no sense. I'm using col-lg-6 an col-md-6, so it should do half & half all the time.

Any ideas?

```
<div class="tab-pane active" id="specification">
<ul class="productinfo">

<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
<h3>Specs</h3>
<ul class="unstyled listoption5"><li>Single bag holds approx. 20 gallons of water. </li><li>Fits mininum 1 inch tree trunk up to a maximum 4 inch tree trunk (Zip 2 bags together to water 5 to 8 inch trees/2 bags=about 40 gallon setup) </li><li>Made of green polyethylene with nylon webbing, black polypro straps and green nylon zippers. </li><li>UV treated to withstand exposure to sunlight. </li><li>2 drip hole locations per bag-Standard drip time of 5 to 9 hours. </li><li>Fill opening fits up to 3" diameter hose.</li><li>Filled with water: 30" Tall x 18" Wide (at base)</li></ul>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
<h3>Product Features</h3>
<ul class="unstyled listoption5">DIRECTIONS FOR USE: <li>Place on tree trunk, with the zippers on the uphill side of the tree. </li><li>Wrap both sides around trunk (1" to 4" dia. trunk*) until zippers meet. </li><li>Two 20 gal. bags zipped together back-to-back - Fits 5 to 8" dia. trunk </li><li>Zip sides of bag together from bottom to top. </li><li>Lift tag to expose fill opening at top of bag. </li><li>Insert hose into fill opening and begin filling with water. </li><li>Fill bag to 1/4 capacity, then gently lift up on straps at top of bag to
</li></ul></div>

<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
<h3>Product Benefits</h3>
<ul class="unstyled listoption5"><li>No more guess work- Provides a professional watering every time. </li><li>Reduces watering frequency-Fill just once a week for most new tree plantings. </li><li>Reduces the amount of time spent at tree- Setup and fill in less than 5 minutes. </li><li>Saves water resources- 100% water absorption with little or no run-off. </li><li>Deep water penetration with each application- Promotes deep root growth and reduces transplant shock.</li></ul>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
<h3>Warranty</h3>
5 Year limited manufacturer warranty from the date of purchase against defects in materials and workmanship.
</div>

<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
<h3>Links</h3>
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.treegator.com/products/specs/TreegatorOrig_SpecSheet.pdf">Spec Sheet</a><br><a href="http://iteminfo.amleo.com/help-desk/items/t/tg20/tg20.pdf">Additional Product Specifications &amp; Handling Precautions</a><br><a target="_blank" href="http://www.treegator.com/products/original/index.html">Double Bag Set Up</a>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
<h3>Application Rates</h3>
Failure to Follow Handling Procedures May Void Manufacturer's Warranty - Do not hang and/or suspend bag from straps. - Before use, remove all sharp objects from area to be irrigated. - Use clean water only. If necessary, filter water through cotton cloth on hose end. - Do not unzip bag when full. - Do not tear or rip fill opening. - Treegator® is not a toy - Keep away from children. - If using water soluble fertilizers, be sure to pre-mix in a separate container before adding mixture to bag. - Treegator® is designed for use on mulch. Failure to do so can result in clogging of drip holes.
</div>

</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You can't have a div as a child of a ul.

Comment: Where is <div class="row"></div> in your markup?

Comment: @j08691 Oh ok I can fix that easily enough. But will that fix the problem I'm experiencing though?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code around every 2 columns:

```
<div class="row">...</div>
```

This will fix the layout, example: http://www.bootply.com/t8m0BopAkO

Comment: The only issue I have with this one is that the content is dynamic. Some products will have a Warranty or Product Benefits, and others will not. I'm not sure how I can determine "Hey, there's been 2, end the row here."